# Heroku Zbar Didn't find libzbar on your system (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, zbar

I have a rails application which uses zbar for barcode recognition. It works fine on my developer machine, but when i tried to deploy it to Heroku my commit was rejected with the following message:

```
app/web.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/zbar-0.2.2/lib/zbar/lib.rb:12:in `rescue in <module:ZBar>': Didn't find libzbar on your system (LoadError) 
app/web.1:  Please install zbar (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) or set ZBAR_LIB if it's in a weird place 
app/web.1:  FFI::Library::ffi_lib() failed with error: library names list must not be empty 
app/web.1:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/zbar-0.2.2/lib/zbar/lib.rb:9:in `<module:ZBar>' 
app/web.1:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/zbar-0.2.2/lib/zbar/lib.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' 
app/web.1:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/zbar-0.2.2/lib/zbar.rb:3:in `require' 
app/web.1:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/zbar-0.2.2/lib/zbar.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' 
app/web.1:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require' 
app/web.1:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
```

Here is my gemfile;

```
gem 'zbar', '~> 0.2.2'
```

my `/.buildpacks`:

```
https://github.com/ballantyne/heroku-buildpack-zbar
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

Why does this happen? How to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

please try in your console:

`heroku config:set ZBAR_LIB=/app/vendor/lib/libzbar.so`

source: https://github.com/willglynn/ruby-zbar/issues/8