# How can I get zbar to deploy on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, zbar

I am using the [ruby-zbar](https://github.com/willglynn/ruby-zbar) gem in a rails app to scan barcodes from jpgs.  I installed the zbar library using homebrew on my local machine and everything works fine.  However, when deploying to Heroku I consistently get errors such as the following:

```
remote:        LoadError: Didn't find libzbar on your system
remote:        Please install zbar (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) or set ZBAR_LIB if it's in a weird place
remote:        FFI::Library::ffi_lib() failed with error: library names list must not be empty
```

I've tried following the advice from this Stack Overflow post ([Heroku Zbar Didn't find libzbar on your system (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410511/heroku-zbar-didnt-find-libzbar-on-your-system-loaderror)), namely to set the ZBAR_LIB ENV variable to /app/vendor/lib/libzbar.so, or failing that to run heroku bash and try to find a file named libzbar.so and point ZBAR_LIB to its path.

However, I can't seem to find the heroku buildpack referenced in the original Stack Overflow post (the link to https://github.com/ballantyne/heroku-buildpack-zbar goes to a 404 page), so I can't replicate the solution outlined there.

I have tried all of the following buildpacks:

```
https://github.com/generalui/heroku-buildpack-zbar
https://github.com/robert-wallis/heroku-buildpack-zbar
https://github.com/robert-wallis/heroku-buildpack-zbar/tree/patch-1
```

During the build process I can see hopeful messages like this:

```
remote: -----> Multipack app detected
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> ZBAR app detected
remote: -----> Downloading and installing ZBAR
remote: -----> Configuring ZBAR
remote: -----> Make!
remote: -----> Make install !!!
remote: -----> Writing profile script
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.1
```

But setting ZBAR_LIB to /app/vendor/lib/libzbar.so gives me some version of this error:

```
remote:        LoadError: Didn't find libzbar on your system
remote:        Please install zbar (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) or set ZBAR_LIB if it's in a weird place
remote:        FFI::Library::ffi_lib() failed with error: Could not open library '/app/vendor/lib/libzbar.so': /app/vendor/lib/libzbar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And trying to find libzbar.so on heroku run bash has not been successful for me -- I can see many files that are similar in name (even a libzbar.rc) but none that fits the bill.

```
~ $ find / -name '*libzbar*'
find: `/var/lib/polkit-1': Permission denied
/app/vendor/zbar/plugin/.deps/plugin_libzbarplugin_la-plugin.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/qt/.deps/qt_libzbarqt_la-QZBar.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/qt/.deps/qt_libzbarqt_la-QZBarThread.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/qt/.deps/qt_libzbarqt_la-moc_QZBarThread.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/qt/.deps/qt_libzbarqt_la-moc_QZBar.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/gtk/.deps/gtk_libzbargtk_la-zbargtk.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/gtk/.deps/gtk_libzbargtk_la-zbarmarshal.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-symbol.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-video.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-error.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/processor/zbar_libzbar_la-lock.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/processor/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-lock.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/processor/zbar_libzbar_la-lock.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/processor/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-null.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/processor/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-x.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/processor/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-posix.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/processor/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-lock.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/processor/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-win.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-config.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-processor.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-refcnt.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-convert.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-video.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-window.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/video/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-null.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/video/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-v4l1.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/video/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-v4l2.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/video/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-vfw.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-processor.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-image.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-refcnt.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-error.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/qrcode/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-qrdectxt.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/qrcode/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-binarize.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/qrcode/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-isaac.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/qrcode/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-rs.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/qrcode/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-qrdec.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/qrcode/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-bch15_5.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/qrcode/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-util.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-video.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-config.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-processor.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-convert.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-window.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-refcnt.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-error.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-img_scanner.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-image.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.libs/zbar_libzbar_la-symbol.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-img_scanner.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-image.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/window/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-null.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/window/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-dib.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/window/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-xv.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/window/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-x.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/window/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-ximage.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/window/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-win.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-img_scanner.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/libzbar.rc
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-symbol.o
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-config.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-decoder.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-config.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-convert.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-processor.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-symbol.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-scanner.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-error.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-jpeg.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-video.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-window.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-refcnt.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-svg.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-img_scanner.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-image.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-window.lo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/decoder/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-code39.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/decoder/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-pdf417.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/decoder/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-qr_finder.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/decoder/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-i25.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/decoder/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-ean.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/decoder/.deps/zbar_libzbar_la-code128.Plo
/app/vendor/zbar/zbar/zbar_libzbar_la-convert.lo
```

Has anyone had success getting zbar to run on heroku?  If so, what buildpack did you use?  I would be thrilled to learn how to make this work.

Comment: Some updates, in case anyone is following along:  1) I am now using the apt-buildpack with libzbar-dev in the aptfile.  2) Bashing into Heroku, I can now find the libzbar.so file that was missing before: (find / -name "libzbar.so" => /app/.apt/usr/lib/libzbar.so).  3) I set the ENV variable ZBAR_LIB to ZBAR_LIB=/app/.apt/usr/lib/libzbar.so.  4) However, I push to Heroku and get the same error as before:  Could not open library '/app/.apt/usr/lib/libzbar.so': /app/.apt/usr/lib/libzbar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what ultimately worked for me:

1) I needed to use the apt-buildpack and the ruby buildpack in tandem.

Command line:

```
heroku buildpacks
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

2) Then I created a file called Aptfile (no extension), placed it at the root of my project folder, and the only line in it is:

Aptfile:

```
libzbar-dev
```

Finally, I had to not require zbar in my gemfile, and require it separately in the code where I was processing the barcode:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'zbar', :require => false
```

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  require 'zbar'

  def index
    path = "#{Rails.public_path}/barcode.jpg"
    jpeg = File.binread(path)
    z = ZBar::Image.from_jpeg(jpeg)
    r = z.process
    @barcode = r.first.data
  end
end
```

Comment: I had to also add `ENV['ZBAR_LIB'] = "/app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzbar.so"` to my production configuration

Answer (score 1):

I was having a really tough time getting not just Heroku to use the right Zbar, but Circle CI as well. I tried using Apt on the CI server to get the dev version, but could not get it working because of weird dependency issues. I ended up creating a heroku buildpack to take care of patching and building the right version, and I wrote a script to get the CI server to do the same.

Heroku:
https://github.com/sheck/heroku-buildpack-zbar

Circle CI:
https://gist.github.com/sheck/475e0c8f2d9f618f1eca

Answer (score 0):

andy they have a success stories coming out of here check it out

https://github.com/willglynn/ruby-zbar/issues/8